# remove multiple object from array and return updated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

trying to remove multiple object from array,solution i did is fine and working but what i want is i don't want to filter twice, want in a single way

so could you help me for best solution

**Example**

```js
 const arrList = [{v:'1',l:'label1'},{v:'2',l:'label2'}, 
                  {v:'3',l:'label3'}, {v:'4',l:'label4'}, 
                  {v:'5',l:'label5'}]
const filter1 = arrList.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label1')
const filter3 = filter1.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label3')
console.log(filter3);
```

Comment: arrList.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label1' && a.l !== 'label3')

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 statement to filter, first not equal to `label1` and another statement `label3`. You can combine them in a single statement with AND `&&` operator, as follow

```
const filter1 = arrList.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label1' && a.l !== 'label3')
```

Comment: please avoid just pasting code without any explanation

Comment: @user2682863 just added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a much simpler solution:

```
arrList.filter((a) => !['label1', 'label3'].includes(a.l))
```

Comment: this is just an example https://jsperf.com/array-includes-vs-array-indexof

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` to combine logical statements in to a single `filter()` expression:

```js
const arrList = [{v:'1',l:'label1'},{v:'2',l:'label2'},{v:'3',l:'label3'}, {v:'4',l:'label4'},{v:'5',l:'label5'}]
const filtered = arrList.filter(a => a.l !== 'label1' && a.l !== 'label3')
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this!

```js
 const arrList = [{v:'1',l:'label1'},{v:'2',l:'label2'}, 
                  {v:'3',l:'label3'}, {v:'4',l:'label4'}, 
                  {v:'5',l:'label5'}]
const filter1 = arrList.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label1' && a.l !== 'label3')
console.log(filter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

const filter3 = arrList.filter((a) => a.l !== 'label1' && a.l !== 'label3')

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it like this.

```
const myFilter = arrList.filter(label => label.l !== 'label1' && label.l !== 'label3');
```